# cancelling acpi compatibility check at winpe boot

Tags: windows, system, legacy, acpi

My task is to load a program i built separately from the OS (it performs a set of actions on the system files so it must be done before the OS boots) on an embedded system. yea i know...

I chose to place it in a clean winpe.wim (got it from Windows AIK). everything works fine on modern bios computers, but when i try it on the embedded system i get stuck at the ACPI boot check: the bios on this system is non-acpi (standard hal)

restrictions : replacing BIOS / getting other winpe aren't options for now.

can i somehow disable the acpi-compatibility check in the winpe i got? through bcdedit maybe? any advice that will help me with this riddle is very appreciated.

also- the boot is performed form a bootable CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured a workaround, if anyone ever needs this:

- shrinked the partition on the embedded system and created a second one
- installed another win2000 there and placed my program to run at start up
- disabled explorer.exe and all unnecessary components

now this partition serves as PE replacement and can perform actions on the main os files if the user boots into it and runs my program